# Interrupt and DMA, what happens in the background?

Tags: c, memory, system, interrupt, dma

I'm trying to understand how Interrupts are handled by the system and how does it work if there is a DMA integrated in the system.

I will express what I understood until now, and I would like to have some feedback if I'm right or not.

In order for the system to catch I/O actions performed by some device, the system uses what's called Interrupts. 
The system sets up interrupts for given actions (we're interested in, for example typing on a keyboard), and once the action is performed the system catches it.

Now I have some doubts, once we catch an Interrupt what happens in the background? What are the overheads? What has does the CPU needs to set up? Is there a context switch? How does the interrupt handler works?

The CPU has to do some work in order to handle the interrupt, does it read the registers and writes the "message" in the memory, in order for the user to see it?

If we have a DMA, instead, once the CPU catches the Interrupt it doesn't need to handle the memory access for the device, thus it can perform other thing until the DMA interrupts the CPU telling him that the transfer it completed and that the CPU can safely close the handling?

As you can see there is some stuff I need to clarify. I would really appreciate your help. I know that an answer to all those questions could be written in one book, but all I need is to know how the things are connected, to get an intuition on what's going on behind the scenes in order to reason more easily about it.

Comment: This is a very broad question and I fear it will need to be closed for exactly that reason. Some of your questions, like "is there a context switch", for example, lead to the assumption that you need to find a stronger distinction between bare metal things and high-level OS events happening, and what's done by the hardware and how the software would need to react.

Comment: Yes but as I wrote, I would just need an idea on how the concepts are connected, and not a too detailed answer (because it could take too much). The question about the context switch was just to understand whether the kernel does a switch to another process to start the interrupt handler or if it the interrupt handler gets executed inside the current running process (which I don't think, but it's something I would like to clarify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interrupts are handled by something called Interrupt Service Routines (ISRs). These are functions implemented by the kernel and registered with the hardware. Each type of an interrupt is registered with a separate handler.

When a hardware receives an interrupt, it halts the execution of any running process (on that processor), pushes the state of the process (registers, flags, segments) on the stack and executes the ISR.

Apart from saving the context, the hardware also does one more important thing. It changes the processor context to Privileged mode (lower ring). This is of course if the processor is already not in Ring 0 and if Privileged operations are required by the ISR. There is a flag in the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT) which tells the processor whether it is a user mode exception or a privileged mode exception.

Since these ISRs are written by the kernel they are trusted. These ISRs perform whatever is required for example in case of a keyboard interrupt, it moves the byte reads into the input stream of the foreground process.

After the ISR is done, (signaled by an `iret` instruction on X86), the state of the program is popped off and the execution of the process continues.

Yes, this can be thought of a context switch, but it really isn't since other process is not loaded. It can be just thought of as a halt till a more important job is done.

While this has some overhead, it is not much in case of frequent interrupts like keyboards interrupts (the ISRs are very small) and also these interrupts are very infrequent.

But say there is a hardware that does jobs are very regular interval. Like disk read/write or network card. In this case, interrupting again and again would be very costly.

So what we use is DMA (direct memory access). The processor allocates some physical memory to these hardware. They can access this part of the RAM without halting the process, since the processor's intervention is not required.

They keep doing all the IO they need to, but in the end when the job is done (or if it fails), they signal the processor with a single interrupt.

Comment: Note that a high-level OS with modes etc doesn't need to be present in order to use DMA. It could as well be a RTOS or a bare metal application with no OS. DMA is for example becoming increasingly common in microcontroller programming.

Comment: @Lundin, yes I agree with it. But OP mentioned " Is there a context switch?". So I assumed that he is talking about a multiprocessor, OS supervised environment. I can add a comment at the end of the answer.

Comment: *It changes the processor context to Privileged mode (lower ring).* Obviously not true. Privileged mode is only in *some* cases and not in any interrupt.

Comment: @tilz0R I wrote it that way because I wanted to talk about the ISR being trusted. Anyway, I added a further comment in the same para.

Comment: Thanks for the answer first of all.
I don't get why it isn't a context switch. I mean, if the kernel stops the running process (thus goes in a runnable state), another process should handle the interrupt right? I mean there should be a process where the handler has to be executed, and if is not the current, its probably one that's created (at startup of OS?) just for the ISR.

Comment: @Ergo the concept of a "process" is created by the operating system. A process is nothing but a data structure stored in the kernels memory against a PID. Hardware doesn't recognise a process. When an interrupt happens, it is just some code running. Whether you want to call it a separate process or not it depends on your definition of a process. Maybe you can say it is not the process running. It is something that is above the process. But, there are some interrupts that are specific to the process. In that case they run in the same virtual address space as the current process.

Comment: Like say a divide by 0 exception raised by the hardware. In that case you wouldn't call it a separate. So a good way to think of an interrupt is - the OS suspends all the processes and takes control in its own hands. It is the "OS" running. Whichever way you want to think about it. I called it not a context switch in the traditional sense of a CS. Where one process gives up the processor and other takes it up.

Comment: In reality what is a context switch? The OS changing it `present_running_process` variable and all the data structures along with it. For hardware everything is just one big process. So yes, it is just a matter of perspective

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, thanks for clarifying you're answer

Comment: I wanted to understand this part, also to understand better why in some scenarios handling I/O is better using polling instead of interrupts

Comment: To keep it simple I would say you would use polling only when you always know when the data will be available. Meaning each of your poll will lead to a hit so that you don't waste time polling. Some scenarios in which data is going to come at regular known intervals. But in moat cases interrupt driven IO is better. It is (almost) always more effecient that polling. Another scenario in which you will be forced to use polling is when the IO device doesn't support interrupts. Most modern devices support interrupts. Some old ones don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147960/discussion-between-ergo-and-ajay-brahmakshatriya).

Comment: So actually the speed at which we type generally is very very less as compared to the things happen in modern processor. Between your two keystrokes millions of instructions have already been executed. Remember that processors go at order of Giga Hertz! (Kilo, mega, giga). So even in that scenario the interrupts approach will be better. And when I said that polling is better when it is at regular intervals, I meant when it is at __known__ regular intervals. So the processor knows right when to poll and will definitely get the data. So no wasted polling. In that case it will be effecient.

Comment: In that case it will be effecient. Very less practical cases for that exist. Anyway, the example where you type very fast after an hour for 30 minutes will still be bad, because the processor will keep polling for that idle one hour and polls will be wasted. It doesn't know when you will start typing, so it has to keep on checking. It is a counter case actually.

Comment: 'After the ISR is done, (signaled by an iret instruction on X86), the state of the program is popped off and the execution of the process continues.' - not necessarily on modern mutitasking OS.  The ISR can make a waiting thread ready, and the ISR may exit via the scheduler and so change the set of running threads in favour of the thread that was waiting, ie. a thread/process context change can occur 'immediately'.  This is VERY important for good I/O performance and is the main reason for using preemptive kernels in the first place.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit, I agree. If the interrupt signals the availability of some data on which a thread was waiting, it would make sense to immediately context switch that thread.